# How to provide .net with the pdb data after an assembly has been loaded?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly

Using this method Assembly.Load(Byte(), Byte())
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twt16z2x.aspx
It is possible to provide a byte representation of the pdb file.

Given that an assembly has already been loaded is it possible to provide pdb data after the fact.

Edit: I am talking programmatically. ie not with the debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible in managed code.
And I have no idea how to do it in unmanaged!

Answer (score 1):

you can try going into debug > windows > modules in vs when you're attatched to the process. there you'd locate your assembly, right click on it and select load symbols (or something to that effect).

i have tried that will byte[]-loaded assemblies though..

Comment: I am talking programmatically. ie not with the debugger. I updated the question

Comment: oops, misread the question, i found the same .Load() overload, but you want to load symbols at a later time.. i'll do some digging

Comment: im starting to wonder if this is possible at all, atleast from managed code :/ i found the [Module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.module.aspx) and [ProcessModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.aspx) classes, but they dont seem to be able to load symbols them selvs, but i think they are part of the solution.. you might be able to start a windbg process and load it that way, maybe using info from the classe above.. sorry i coundt provide a complete solution :/